# How to order a field and display them in string format

Tags: sql-server

I am having a table

```
FieldName | FieldOrder 
-----------------------
Srl       |  1
Data      |  2
Content   |  4
Field     |  3
Data1     |  6
Field1    |  5
```

I need to display them in a particular order based on the fieldOrder.

```
[Srl],[Data],[Field],[Content],[Field1],[Data1]
```

I tried this code.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        select @cols = STUFF(( SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) from (SELECT FieldName,FieldOrder from CatogoryFieldValueMaster where CatogoryId = 1 and
        CompanyId= 1 order By FieldOrder Asc) fieldname FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
        print @cols
```

It shows an error as

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.
```

Please help me

Comment: Looks like you have this problem to solve some other problem- typical XY problem case. Curious why do you want ordered columns in a variable?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid duplicate values in the `FieldName` column with the `DISTINCT` calues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear - you can not use `ORDER BY` to sort rows in the derived table, unless `TOP`, `OFFSET` or `FOR XML` is also specified. But, the interesting part is the `DISTINCT` clause in your statement. I assume that you want to remove the possible duplicate values in the `FieldName` column. You have at least these options to generate the expected output:

Statement (using `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation) with duplicates:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT CONCAT(',', FieldName)
    FROM CatogoryFieldValueMaster
    WHERE (CatogoryId = 1) AND (CompanyId = 1) 
    ORDER BY FieldOrder ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    1, 1,''
)
PRINT @cols
```

Statement (using `FOR XML PATH` for string aggregation) without duplicates:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STUFF(
    (
    SELECT CONCAT(',', FieldName)
    FROM (
        SELECT FieldName, FieldOrder, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FieldName ORDER BY FieldOrder ASC) AS rn
        FROM CatogoryFieldValueMaster
        WHERE (CatogoryId = 1) AND (CompanyId = 1) 
    ) t
    WHERE t.rn = 1
    ORDER BY FieldOrder ASC
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),
    1, 1,''
)
PRINT @cols
```

If you use SQL Server 2017+, string aggregation can be easily done with `STRING_AGG()`:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @cols = STRING_AGG(FieldName, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FieldOrder)
FROM CatogoryFieldValueMaster
PRINT @cols
```

Comment: Thank you string aggregation really helped it with simple code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try a loop

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cntr INT, @totalFields INT
SET @cntr =1
SET @cols =''
SET @totalFields= 
    MAX(FieldOrder) 
    from CatogoryFieldValueMaster 
        where CatogoryId = 1 and CompanyId= 1
WHILE @cntr<=@totalFields
BEGIN
        SELECT @cols = CONCAT(@cols,',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName)) from CatogoryFieldValueMaster where CatogoryId = 1 and
        CompanyId= 1 and FieldOrder =@cntr
SET @cntr=@cntr+ 1
END
        print @cols
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF(
( 
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
from 
(
SELECT FieldName,FieldOrder 
from CatogoryFieldValueMaster 
where CatogoryId = 1 
and CompanyId= 1 
) fieldname 
order By FieldOrder Asc
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

print @cols


--or for duplicates
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @cols = STUFF(
( 
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FieldName) 
from 
(
SELECT FieldName, MIN(FieldOrder) as FieldOrder
from CatogoryFieldValueMaster 
where CatogoryId = 1 
and CompanyId= 1
group by FieldName 
) fieldname 
order By FieldOrder Asc
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

print @cols
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Query Works Fine your Case:

SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + NAME 
              FROM @TAB 
              ORDER BY ID
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '')

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT 
      @cols = COALESCE(@cols+',','') + QUOTENAME(FieldName)

FROM CatogoryFieldValueMaster

ORDER BY FieldOrder

PRINT @cols

Comment: Thanks it worked, but one item was missing while printing